# Ceph cluster not working after reboot in Ubuntu 16.04, works in 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, cluster-computing, ubuntu-16.04, ceph

I've setup a Ceph (Jewel) Cluster on 4 VMs running Ubuntu 16.04 following [this guide](http://docs.ceph.com/docs/jewel/start/quick-ceph-deploy/).

Everything worked as expected until I rebooted the VMs. Running `ceph health` or `ceph -w` doesn't do anything and is stuck until exiting with `CTRL-c`. The exact same Ceph setup instead on 4 VMs running Ubuntu 14.04 works without problems even after reboot.

Is there something I need to manually start after a reboot in 16.04 or is there something wrong with my setup of the cluster?

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you wait for a little longer time, like 5 minutes, it would show "authentication timeout in 300 seconds". Then check the network connection between ceph nodes, SELinux and firewall configuration. Ceph uses 6789 port.